# JQuery Mobile do SilentScroll for Another Page after Redirect to that page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, scroll

How to do scroll to section on the page that wanted to see after click button on header (on every page) than redirected to another page after that automatically scroll to that section on that another page... ?

I have already do this, but it is only work when I am on that page that there is the wanted section, but if I on another page, it is not working only redirect to that page but not scrolling) Tq

Here is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[data-role*='page']").live('pageshow', function(event, ui){
        $('a.logo_print').click(function(event){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.mobile.silentScroll($("#how_to_print").offset().top);
            },100);
        });
    });
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the time from 100 to 1000 or 1500, prefer to 1500 in order to work on any device ... :) Thx a lot

```
 $('a.logo_print').click(function(event){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.mobile.silentScroll($("#how_to_print").offset().top);
            },1000);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you pass the SectionName on the SecondPage as a QueryString parameter.

```
<a href="#page2&val=val1">link</a>
```

In the `pageShow` method; you can extract the QueryString param and use `silentScroll` as in your sample code above.

You can get the clicked URL from `ui.prevPage.context.URL`